# Creating dictionary from space separated key=value string in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have string as follows:

```
s = 'key1=1234 key2="string with space" key3="SrtingWithoutSpace"'
```

I want to convert in to a dictionary as follows:

```
key  | value
-----|--------  
key1 | 1234
key2 | string with space
key3 | SrtingWithoutSpace
```

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: What should happen if your string is `'key1=""foo"bar key2="baz'`?

Comment: I am parsing output of a log file and I do not expect output in any other format.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> import re
>>> dict(re.findall(r'(\S+)=(".*?"|\S+)', s))
{'key3': '"SrtingWithoutSpace"', 'key2': '"string with space"', 'key1': '1234'}
```

If you also want to strip the quotes:

```
>>> {k:v.strip('"') for k,v in re.findall(r'(\S+)=(".*?"|\S+)', s)}
```

Comment: I can't quite understand why the regex is r'(\S+)=(".*?"|\S+)', as opposed to r'(\S+)=(\".*?\"|\S+)'. Do you not need to escape the special character? Or do you just know that " has no special meaning in python regex?

Answer (score 29):

> The [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) class makes it easy to write
>   lexical analyzers for simple syntaxes
>   resembling that of the Unix shell.
>   This will often be useful for writing
>   minilanguages, (for example, in run
>   control files for Python applications)
>   or for parsing quoted strings.

```
import shlex

s = 'key1=1234 key2="string with space" key3="SrtingWithoutSpace"'

print dict(token.split('=') for token in shlex.split(s))
```

Comment: `dict(token.split('=', 1)`, otherwise what happens if there is a `=` in the value?