# Converting log file line to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a log file generated by an external program I can't control that consists of a key-value pairs separated by spaces and I can't find a simple way to parse this. For example, a line would contain something like

```
time="2017-10-03T15:13:34Z" level=info msg="Some information message" 
time="2017-10-03T15:13:35Z" level=warn msg="Some basic message" err="More details on error"
```

I can't split on spaces because of the strings and I'm not entirely sure how to deal with this using regex because not everything is bounded in quotes.

Is there a simple way to convert a single line into a dictionary (or JSON)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating dictionary from space separated key=value string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764547/creating-dictionary-from-space-separated-key-value-string-in-python)

Comment: @DaveBensonPhillips Sorry, I didn't see this in my suggestions. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `shlex.split` function to preserves spaces inside quotes.

Comment: Works great, didn't know there was this in the library. Thank you very much, I will accept the answer when I can.